# Работа со сценами

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 сцены:`GameMainMenu` и `Game`. Хочу перенести объект `WorldName` (TextMeshPro) с одной сцены на другую, но когда я пытаюсь обращаться к сцене, на которую переношу объект, то получаю сообщение о том, что сцена не найдена. Для проверки я при помощи `Debug.Log()` выводил на экран имя сцены, но каково моё было удивление, когда я получал ответ, в котором сказано, что У меня имя моей сцены `Null`, но при использовании `LoadScene()` всё прекрасно загружалось. Помогите разобраться, что не так.
P.S. Сперва я нахожусь на сцене  `GameMainMenu`.
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class JoinToWorld : MonoBehaviour
{
    Button WorldButton;
    TextMeshProUGUI WorldName; // На другую сцену я кидаю вот эту табличку TMP
    Scene GameScene; // Сцена, к которой я обращаюсь
    GameObject SinglePlayerMenu;
    void Start()
    {
        WorldButton = GetComponent<Button>();
        GameScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Game"); // По имени обращаюсь к сцене Game
        WorldName = WorldButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        WorldName.text = $"{WorldButton.name}";

        WorldButton.onClick.AddListener(PlayInSelectedWorld);

    }
    public void PlayInSelectedWorld() // Вызываю функцию по нажатию кнопки
    {
        Debug.Log(GameScene.name);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game", LoadSceneMode.Single); // Сцена запускается спокойно
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(WorldName.gameObject, GameScene); // А вот объект на нее не перемещается по вышеупомянутой причине
    }
```

Comment: У вас описана переменная `Scene Game;`, а откуда берётся переменная `GameScene` - непонятно. Описка, на самом деле код другой?

Comment: А, это я небольшие правки вносил, Тут тоже написано GameScene, Но проблема не в этом

Comment: А что вам мешает добавить такую же строку GameScene = ... и во вторую функцию, перед Move? Чтобы заполнить эту переменную. Я бы попробовал так сделать.

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не работает эта схема

Answer (score 0):

Додумался: нужно было просто написать `DontDestroyOnLoad(object)`, тогда я могу взаимодействовать с этим объектом на любых сценах